# Powershell String Length Validation

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I created a really simple `HelloWorld.ps1` Power-shell script which accepts a `Name` parameter, validates its length and then prints a hello message, for example if you pass `John` as `Name`, it's supposed to print `Hello John!`.

Here is the Power-shell script:

```
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $Name
)
# Length Validation
if ($Name.Length > 10) {
    Write-Host "Parameter should have at most 10 characters."
    Break
}
Write-Host "Hello $Name!"
```

And here is the command to execute it:

```
.\HelloWorld.ps1 -Name "John"
```

The strange behavior is every time that I execute it:

- It doesn't perform validation, so it accepts `Name` parameters longer than 10 characters.
- Every time I execute it, it creates and updates a file named `10` without any extension.

What's the problem with my script and How can I validate string length in PowerShell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The problem - Using wrong operator**

Using wrong operators is a common mistake in PowerShell. In fact [`>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1) is [output redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1) and it sends output of the left operand to the specified file in the right operand.

For example `$Name.Length > 10` will output length of `Name` in a file named `10`.

**How can I validate string length?**

You can use [`-gt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) which is [greater than operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) this way:

```
if($Name.Length -gt 10)
```

**Using `ValidateLength` attribute for String Length Validation**

You can use [`[ValidateLength(int minLength, int maxlength)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714452(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute this way:

```
param (
    [ValidateLength(1,10)]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $Name
)
Write-Host "Hello $Name!"
```