# Is it possible to set a Powershell variable to a fixed N chars?

Tags: .net, powershell

I am wondering if it is possible to set a variable in Powershell to N number of Chars.

Example #1

I want variable $Name to always be fixed to 5 char. 
So if i where to write:

`$Name = 'Alex'`

The output I expect would be: 'Alex '

Alex contains 4 chars therefore the variable would understand and add necessary space chars.

Example #2

`$Name = 'A'`

Output: 'A    '

'A' is one char and therefore the variable should add 4 spaces.

Is there a way to set this rule for the variable `$Name` ?

Comment: What should happen if you set `$Name = "MoreThanFiveCharacters"`?

Comment: Short answer: no, unless you futzed around with custom types that perform this validation and have a conversion from/to `string`, which is almost certainly more trouble than it's worth (read: you want a "proper" programming language for this and not PowerShell).

Comment: this will let you pad a value out with spaces >>> `('{0,4}' -f 'a')` <<< the result is `   a`. [*grin*]

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am using String length validation for that there is a great discussion on that in stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421158/powershell-string-length-validation

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi, I agree with you but im in a position where i have to do it in powershell. 

Something like: while ($Name.Length -lt 30){
    $Space = ' ';
    $Name +=   $Space
}

Comment: You can do string validation/padding in PowerShell through functions; that's not the issue. The issue is embedding this into a variable in such a way that it never fails or reverts back to a plain old `string` no matter the use case; *that* is more trouble than it's worth. You're best off defining and checking such things at the edges of your input/output layers and use a plain old `string` inside the scripts themselves.

Comment: [Why would you like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to have a fixed length string anyway? Please describe the use case, maybe there are solutions out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell 5.1 and up you can create a custom [`ArgumentTransformationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute) subclass:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation

class StringLengthTransformationAttribute : ArgumentTransformationAttribute
{
    [ValidateRange(0,1024)]
    [int]$Length = 5

    [char]$PaddingChar = ' '

    StringLengthTransformationAttribute()
    {
    }

    StringLengthTransformationAttribute([int]$Length)
    {
        $this.Length = $Length
    }

    StringLengthTransformationAttribute([int]$Length, [char]$PaddingChar)
    {
        $this.Length = $Length
        $this.PaddingChar = $PaddingChar
    }

    [object]
    Transform([EngineIntrinsics]$engineIntrinsics, [object]$inputData)
    {
        return $inputData -replace "^(.{$($this.Length)}).*$",'$1' |% PadRight $this.Length $this.PaddingChar
    }
}
```

Now, when applied to a variable, it'll transform whatever you assign to it:

```
[StringLengthTransformation()]$Name = 'Alex'
# $Name is now 'Alex '

$Name = 'Alexandra'
# $Name is now 'Alexa'

[StringLengthTransformation(10, '-')]$Name = 'Alex'
# $Name is now 'Alex------'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
function Set-FixedVariable {

    param( [parameter(mandatory)][string]$name,
           [parameter(mandatory)][string]$value,
           [parameter(mandatory)][int]$size
    )

    $sb = [System.Text.Stringbuilder]::new( ' ' * $size )
    [void]$sb.Insert(0, $value)

    Set-Variable -Name $name -Value $sb.ToString().Substring(0, $size) -Scope Script -Force

    return $value

}


Set-FixedVariable -name 'ab' -value 'Alex' -size 10

$ab.Length
```

Comment: Would this not suffice?

while ($Name.Length -lt 30){
    $Space = ' ';
    $Name +=   $Space
}

warp this in a function and make it resuable?

Comment: This doesn't prevent modifying `$ab`. Running `$ab = "bob";$ab.length` returns 3.

Comment: Aside from @vonPryz' valid point, your function will only work as intended when called directly from the _script_ scope. Otherwise you'll be modifying a different variable, notably when called from another function with a function-local variable or when you include this function in a module and call it from the outside. Finally, though this is just a quibble: a `Set-` command shouldn't return anything, unless `-PassThru` is also specified. That the function currently returns the _original_, unpadded value adds to the confusion.

Comment: This was thought as a Brief help for the asker, not as a template for a global module considering each circumstance.

Comment: Then please clearly state the limitations of your solution as a preamble in your answer. Answers are never _just_ for the asker; many readers will come here over time, with (slightly) different requirements, so it's important to tell them about assumptions and limitations and shortcuts taken. Aside from that, your answer currently does not even mention that your solution does _not_ satisfy the asker's express requirement to also enforce the padding _on assignment_.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers I feel like people are making this too difficult, .length should be sufficient.

```
function Add-Spaces
{
Param (
    [string]$Name
)

do
{
    $name.length
    $name += ' '
}
while ($name.Length -ne '5')
}

$name = 'Bas'

Add-Spaces -Name $name
```

Comment: This satisfies none of the original requirements (constraining a string _variable_ to a fixed number of characters, with space padding for shorter values). Your function doesn't even return a padded value, it returns an array of string lengths (by implicitly and presumably accidentally outputting `$name.Length`). The _intended_ functionality can be had without a function, by simply calling `$name.PadRight(5, ' ')`, but that still doesn't address the desire to enforce the length, and, more importantly that both the length restriction and padding should be enforced on _assigning_ to `$name`.